# c# sync only new files to amazon s3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, synchronization

I'm uploading all my local files to s3 using this code:

```
static string bucketName = "s3bucket";
static string directoryPath = @"C:\data\";    

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        TransferUtility directoryTransferUtility =
            new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2));

        TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest request =
            new TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Directory = directoryPath,
                SearchPattern = "*.xml"
            };

        directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(request);
        MessageBox.Show("Upload completed");

    } catch (AmazonS3Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I run the code again all files are re-uploaded to s3 and that's a bad idea if let's say we have 1000+ files in our local directory.

I know I can compare file by file because aws stores the md5 of each file. **So my question is can I do this with a command that comes preinstalled? Do I have to recursively compare file by file?** If the sync command exists on awscli bundle (`aws s3 sync ./sourceDir s3://bucketname/`) does it exists on c# as well?

Answer (score 0):

All the files will be replaced. [S3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html) , but if you still want to check files you can use some function like this

```
    ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest()
    {
        BucketName = "Your Bucket name",
        Delimiter = "/",
        Prefix = "location"
    };

    public bool CheckFile(ListObjectsRequest request)
    {
        bool res = false;

        try
        {

            ListObjectsResponse response = s3client.ListObjects(request);

            if (response.S3Objects != null && response.S3Objects.Count > 0)
            {
                S3Object o = response.S3Objects.Where(x => x.Size != 0 && x.LastModified > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (o != null)
                {
                    //you can use thes fields
                    // o.Key; //o.Size, //o.LastModified

                    res = true;

                }

            }
            else
            {
                res = false;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: I am currently doing that but I was wondering if there is a sync option